# Sql Query to print ename and dname please share me how to write query in oracle or Mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle10g

**Employee**
Eid ename   salary
1   charles 3000
2   kiran   2000
3   naveen  8000
4   manju   7000

**Department**

deptid  dname
101     charles
102     kiran
103     naveen
104     manju

**Register**

deptid  eid

101     1
102     2
103     3
104     4

write a query to print (employee) ename and (department)dname.

Comment: search for **"how to select records from a table using MySQL"**

Comment: select * from empolyee

Comment: I am shocked to know that `mysql` has a version called `oracle10g`.

Comment: no ...i want query to execute both oracle10g and mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ename, b.depart, c.eid
FROM  employee a
INNER JOIN department b on a.ename=b.dname
INNER JOIN register c on b.deptid=c.deptid
where a.ename=b.dname and b.deptid=c.deptid;
```